# Hide an invalid date result in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

Using Excel Mac 2011. I am trying to create an invoice based on a time sheet in a workbook. I want the invoice to show a worked date only if a date is entered on the time sheet. When I link the cells between the 2 worksheets with ='Time Card'!B6, I get the date 1/0/00 on the invoice when there is no date entered on the time sheet. I tried IFERROR, =IFERROR('Time Card'!B5,""), but get the same result. How can I have it generate a blank value instead of that? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You just need to update formatting of the cell using a custom format.  [This page](http://www.ozgrid.com/Excel/CustomFormats.htm) has the basics.

key point is this sentence along with the table of date formats

> It is very important to understand how cell formats are seen by Excel. Excel see a cells format as having four Sections. These are, from left to right Positive numbers, Negative Numbers, Zero Values and Text values. Each of these Sections are separated by a semi colon (;)

Basically you need to create a format that does something different for 0 values since this is what excel is returning.

`yyyy-mmm-dd` would return 2017-Apr-19 for today 1900-Jan-01 for 0 (day 0 in excels dating system) and an error for any negative values.

`dd/mm/yyyy;"neg value";-` would still return 2017-Apr-19 for today a "-" for 0 and the text "neg value" if you get a negative value for some reason

Drop the "-" at the end and it would return a blank for 0 values.

`dd/mm/yyyy;"neg value";`

Comment: Thanks. I think I understand. The value I am trying to format is actually the difference between 2 times. So I would use hh:mm ? Also to do this for a text field use "text"?

Comment: Not sure what you mean for a text field if you are comparing two times it should be a number.  For formatting you could use `[hh]:mm;;` which would return a blank cell if it is equal to 0.  The `[]` just allows the hour values to go higher then 24 which is likely not needed unless you are summing the values together.

Comment: got it, thanks. I had another field that was coming as "0" when no value so I formatted it as "";neg value"; and that worked. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Should mention the "neg value" is just to be more explicit as to why the times are erroring its not really needed.